# Fastest way to access given lines of text file with and without using GZip and the Jar File (GZip in memory?)

Tags: java, gzip, text-files

I have given number (5-7) of large UTF8 text files (7 MB). In unicode their size is about 15MB each.

I need to load given parts of a given file. The files are known and does not change. I would like to access and load lines at give place as fast as possible. I load these lines adding HTML tags and display them in a JEditorPane. I know the bottle neck will be the rendering by the JEditorPane of the HTML generated but for now I would like to concentrate on the file access performances.

Moreover the user can search for a given word in all the files.

For now the code I use is :

```
private static void loadFile(String filename, int startLine, int stopLine) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);                
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        for (int j = startLine; j <= stopLine; j++) {
            //here I add HTML tags
            //or do string comparison in case of search by the user 
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Now my questions :

As the number of parts of each file is known, 67 in my case (for each file), I could create 67 smaller files. It will be "faster" to load a given part but be slower when I do a search as I must open each of the 67 file.

I have not done bench marking but my feelings says that opening 67 files in case of a search is much longer than the time to perform empty reader.readlines when loading a part of the file.

So in my case it is better to have a single larger file. Do you agree with that ?

If I put each large file in the resource, I mean in the Jar file, will the performance be worse, if yes is it significantly worse ?

And the related question is what if I zip each file to spare size. As far as I undersand a Jar file is simply a zip file.

I think I don't know how unzipping works. If I zip a file, will the file be decompressed in memory or will my program be able to access the given lines I need directly on the disk.
Same for the Jar file will it be decompressed in memory.

If unzipping is not in memory can someone edit my code to use zip file.

Final question and the most important for me. I could increase all the performance if everything was performed in memory, but due to unicode and the quite large files this could easily result in a heap of memory of more than 100MB. Is there a possibility of having the zip file loaded in memory and work on that. This would be fast and use only few memory.

Summary of the questions

1. In my case, 1 large file is best than plenty of small ones.
2. If files are zipped, is the unzip process (GZipInputStream) performed in memory. Is all the file unzipped in memory and then access or is it possible to access it directly on disk.
3. If yes to question 2, can someone edit my code to be able to do it ?
4. MOST IMPORTANT : is it possible to have the zip file loaded in memory and how ?

I hope my questions are clear enough. ;-)

**UPDATE** : Thanks to Mike for the getResourceAsStream hint, I get it working

Notice that benchmarking give that load the Gzip file is efficient, but in ma case is too slow.

~200 ms for the gzip file
~125 ms for the standard file so 1.6 times faster.

Assuming that the resource folder is called resources

```
private static void loadFile(String filename, int startLine, int stopLine) {
    try {                           
        GZIPInputStream zip = new GZIPInputStream(this.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/"+filename));            
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(zip, "UTF8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        for (int j = startLine; j <= stopLine; j++) {
            //here I add HTML tags
            //or do string comparison in case of search by the user 
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't explained why you can't load the file into memory as that is the the fastest.  100 MB is not that much memory depending on your system.

Comment: Peter : The program is quite simple. Display parts of text files and search through them. I am asked to program something as "portable" as possible. That means being used on many different systems worldwide and of course even on old machines. When I checked in my start manager (windows), only few programs use more than 100MB so I told myself that would be a good limit. Moreover if other translations are made and I reach for example 10 files or more I can easily go large in memory used. Do you agree we that ? Moreover as I putting HTML generated in a JEditorFrame, the speed bottle neck is that.

Comment: You can check the maximum memory the JVM has and determine whether to use the faster option of loading everything or the slower, but more memory efficient option of reading lines as you need them.  There is often a trade off between memory efficiency and speed (that why having more memory can make a system faster)  In term of portability, you need a means of examining large files efficiently as well (but performance will suffer)

Comment: I agree, especially on the trade off between memory and speed. This made me think that I should let the user decide ! I think I will program both solutions and let the user decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files really aren't changing very often I would suggest using some other data structures.  Creating a hash table of all the words and locations they show up would make searching much faster, creating an index of all the line start positions would make that process much faster.

But, to answer your questions more directly:

1. Yes, one large file is probably still better than many small files, I doubt that reading a line and decoding from UTF8 will be noticeable compared to opening many files, or decompressing many files.
2. Yes, the unzipping process is performed in memory, and on the fly.  It happens as you request data, but acts as a buffered stream, it will decompress entire blocks at a time, so it is actually very efficient.
3. I can't fix your code directly, but I can suggest looking up getResourceAsStream:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29
   This function will open a file that is in a zip / jar file and give you access to it as a stream, automatically decompressing it in memory as you use it.
4. If you treat it as a resource, java will do it all for you, you will have to read up on some of the specifics of handling resources, but java *should* handle it fairly intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it would be quicker for you to load the file(s) into memory. You can then zip around to whatever part of the file you need.
   Take a look at [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for this.
2. The GZipInputStream reads the files into memory as a buffered stream.
3. That's another question entirely :)
4. Again, the zip file will be decompressed in memory depending on what Class you use to open it.